# How do I disable headless mode in Linux?

Tags: linux, hdmi, kvm-switch, headless

I have several computers in my home network, some run Linux, some run Windows, all connected to a 4-port KVM with USB and HDMI. When the power comes back on after an outage, and if I have them all come on at the same time, I can switch to the Windows boxes and I'm able to log into them with no trouble. However, both Linux boxes (one runs Slackware Linux 15.0 and one runs Linux Mint 20.3, if that matters) do not have a display if the KVM isn't focused on them when they're powered on. So, it seems that if there is no keyboard, mouse, and monitor connected to a Linux box when it boots up, it automatically boots up in headless mode, and if I then connect a keyboard, mouse (USB), and monitor (HDMI), the monitor doesn't come on until I restart the computer.

I can find plenty of information about how to run a Linux server headless. However, I can't seem to find any information on how to **disable** this functionality. Is there a way to disable this functionality? I want both Linux boxes to assume there is a keyboard, mouse, and monitor available but not necessarily attached at the moment the computer boots up.

Comment: Linux does not have “headless mode”. However, your KVM might be sort of “underpowered”. A good KVM emulates the presence of all devices even if an input is not active/selected. This means your _hardware_ might select a different primary output.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction, and yes, it sort of is underpowered, probably because it's one of the cheaper ones.  It does not emulate the presence of all (or any, really) devices on ports that are not selected.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I can't seem to find any information on how to disable this functionality.

It's because there is no such functionality. It's not a "mode" (all of the software is fully prepared to deal with keyboards and mice appearing and disappearing on the fly).

The closest thing might be the kernel console selecting a *different output* when all of them are disconnected. The kernel's internal console (virtual terminals) only fully supports being run on a single output, so I suspect that if HDMI is connected at boot it'll choose HDMI, whereas if nothing is connected it'll choose the 1st output which is probably VGA or something.

Use the `video=` kernel option to force a specific output to be enabled (and to set its resolution if your KVM doesn't properly handle EDID), e.g. `video=HDMI-1:1280x1024e` will set that output to "always `e`nabled" at that resolution.

The graphical Xorg and various Wayland compositors are a different case; it becomes the display manager's job to decide when and where to start instances of the graphical login screen (which may well have a different logic from the logged-in session itself). This is almost never based on input devices, however, only on output devices.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and correcting my ignorance.  I suspected that a kernel parameter might help.  Will give this a try when I get home this evening.

Comment: Hmm, that's not working on my Slackware box.  While X is running, the port is called HDMI-0, but if I add that to the kernel options (I use lilo, so I add it to the "append=" line) and reboot, the display still doesn't come on if not connected during boot. :(  Any other ideas?

Comment: Xorg names might not always match kernel (DRI) names; at least with certain xf86-video- drivers they might be off by one. Take a look at `/sys/class/drm/`; I think kernel output names always start at 1. What method do you use to start X – does it start at boot or do you run it from console?

Comment: I poked around in /sys/class/drm/ but didn't see anything that looks like DP, DVI-I, HDMI, VGA, or anything else that indicates a video port.  On this computer, it boots to a text console screen, and I start X when needed.  Thanks for your response.